# Solve linear equation with vectors

Tags: c#, .net, vector, symbolic-math

Which library is available in .NET to solve equations like this efficiently?

[image]

The result should be

[image]

I need this kind of intermediate equation to calculate the minimal distance of a line *g* and a point *P*. Maybe there are some other libraries how have this functionality already included.

Comment: http://www.mathdotnet.com/ has linear algebra support.

Comment: You want `Math.Net`, especially [`Math.Net Numerics`](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to re-iterate the use of `Math.NET`. You want to rewrite your equation in the form of `Ax=b` and they simply code it as:

```
var A = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(new double[,]
{
    {10, -10},
    {10, 10}
});
var b = Vector<double>.Build.Dense(new double[] {8, 1});
var x = A.Solve(b);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

which gives you the solution, i.e. vector `x` as:

```
DenseVector 2-Double
 0.45
-0.35
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. I've played around with Math.NET but was not able to form the right equation to use the solve method.